# Is it possible to call a function using the "on conflict" event?

Tags: postgresql

The `on conflict` used to implement a `upsert` behavior is a wonderful feature.  I'm wondering if I were to find the RFC for the feature whether I might find a way to use the `on conflict` event to call a function, or use something like:

```sql
on conflict
do $$
insert into another table
$$
```

Otherwise, considering myself still new to postgresql, is there a way to "catch" the conflict to enable further intervention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use the `on conflict` keyword to influence other tables. As stated by the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html), the conflict_action may be one of the following only:

```
conflict_action is one of:

    DO NOTHING
    DO UPDATE SET { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT } |
                    ( column_name [, ...] ) = [ ROW ] ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) |
                    ( column_name [, ...] ) = ( sub-SELECT )
                  } [, ...]
              [ WHERE condition ]
```

However, this does not mean there are no workarounds (at least for the `do nothing` command). You may use a function with the combination of the very useful `found` keyword in PostgreSQL to emulate something similar.

```
create or replace function generic_insert(
    p_user_name text
)
  returns boolean
  language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
    insert into users (user_name) values (p_user_name) on conflict do nothing;

    if not found then <your code> end if;

    return found;
end;
$$;
```

The trick here is that the `found` keyword returns "number of rows affected" (of the last executed query). Since `do nothing` did not influence any rows, `found` returns false, hence you'd know through this that your insert caused the `do nothing` portion of the `on conflict` command to trigger. You may of course put whatever code or insert commands you'd like inside the if statement.

Comment: Nice.  The explanation is helpful. The work-around looks sound. Thank you.